# If $X,Y\sim B$ so $X+Y\sim B$?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be random independent variables, such that $X\sim B(n,0.5),Y\sim B(n,0.2)$

> $X+Y$ is also binomial distributed?

My start:

$$X+Y\in \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$$

$$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k} 0.5^k(1-0.5)^{n-k}=\binom{n}{k} 0.5^n$$

$$P(X=t)=\binom{n}{t} 0.5^t(1-0.5)^{n-t}=\binom{n}{t}0.5^n$$

Let as denote $S:=X+Y\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$P(S=\mathscr{L})$

I'm stuck here

Comment: If $X+Y$ is a binomial r.v., then we can determine its parameters $n$ and $p$ by solving the system of equations $\Bbb{E}[X+Y] = np$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = np(1-p)$. But you can easily check that this yields non-integer value for $n$, which is absurd. For a more systematic approach, you may investigate its MGF or its characteristic function.

Comment: Related [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Related_distributions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your main question is: no.

Let's look at special case $n=1$.

Then $X,Y$ both take values in
$\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ so that $X+Y$ take values in $\left\{ 0,1,2\right\} $.

This with

- $P\left(X+Y=0\right)=0.5\times0.2=0.1$
- $P\left(X+Y=1\right)=0.5\times0.8+0.5\times0.2=0.5$
- $P\left(X+Y=2\right)=0.5\times0.8=0.4$

If this distribution is binomial with
parameters $m$ and $p$ then necessarily $m=2$ and $p^{2}=0.4$.
Recalculating the probabilities mentioned above on base of that we find that the distribution of $X+Y$ does *not*
coincide with it.

---

To make my answer more complete: If $X,Y$ are independent random variables distributed binomially with parameters $n,p$ and $m,p$ respectively (so the same probability on a "succes") then indeed $X+Y$ has binomial distribution. This with parameters $n+m,p$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not binomial distributed. In general though there is a very reliable method so establish if a linear combination of *independent* variables follows some distribution: compute their charachteristic function!

So in this case 
$$E[e^{iu(X+Y)}] = E[e^{iuX}]E[e^{iuY}]  = ((1-p_1) + p_1e^{iu})^n((1 - p_2) + p_2e^{iu})^n$$ and with some algebra you can readily see that this is not in the form $((1-p) + pe^{iu})^n$

Comment: I guess you forgot the power to the $n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you were attempting to do, by the way, was the following.

$X\sim \mathcal B(n,0.5), Y\sim\mathcal B(n,0.2), X\perp Y$

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=s) & = \binom{n}{s}0.5^s(1-0.5)^{n-s} \;\mathbf 1_{s\in\{0..n\}}
\\[1ex] & = \binom{n}{s}\frac 1{2^n}\;\mathbf 1_{s\in\{0..n\}}
\\[2ex] \mathsf P(Y=t) & = \binom{n}{t}0.2^t(1-0.2)^{n-t}\;\mathbf 1_{t\in\{0..n\}}
\\[1ex] & = \binom{n}{t}\frac{4^{n-t}}{5^n}\;\mathbf 1_{t\in\{0..n\}}
\\[3ex]
\mathsf P(X+Y=k)
 & = \sum_{h=\max(0, k-n)}^{\min(n,k)}\mathsf P(X=k-h)\mathsf P(Y=h)\;\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0..2n\}}
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{h=\max(0, k-n)}^{\min(n,k)}\binom{n}{k-h}\binom{n}{h}\,\frac{4^{n-h}}{10^n}\;\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0..2n\}}
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k-h}\binom{n}{h}\,\frac{4^{n-h}}{10^n}\;\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0..n\}}
+ \sum_{h=k-n}^{n}\binom{n}{k-h}\binom{n}{h}\,\frac{4^{n-h}}{10^n}\;\mathbf 1_{k\in\{n+1..2n\}}
\end{align}$

Thus clearly not a binomial distribution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are stuck because the result you are trying to show isn't quite right. To the best of my knowledge, there is no named distribution that $X + Y$ follows, and it most definitely is not binomial.

As a simple illustration why, simply consider the $n=1$ case, which has PMF $P(X+Y=0) = 0.4$, $P(X + Y = 1) = 0.35$, $P(X + Y= 2) = 0.25$. If this were binomial, $n$ would have to equal 2 because the support of this distribution is $\{0,1,2\}$ and $p$ would have to equal $0.5$ because $P(X + Y=2) = p^2 \implies p = 0.5$. However, if we looked at $P(X+Y=0) = 1-p^2 \implies p = \sqrt{0.6}$ which draws a contradiction.

The only case where summing binomials gives you another binomial is when the probabilities are equal, thus if $X_1 \sim B(n_1, p)$ and $X_2 \sim B(n_2, p)$ then $X_1 + X_2 \sim B(n_1 + n_2, p)$.